What do I need to install to connect to a remote Oracle database?
I need to install an Oracle client on an Ubuntu server (20.04.6) so that Perl scripts can connect to a remote Oracle database.
The database version is "Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production". Perl is version 5.30.
It's been ages since I've needed to install an Oracle client and I've never done it on a Linux machine. I also need to build the DBD::Oracle module for Perl's use. And IIRC, that process depends on some C headers from Oracle?
Can anyone point me to the file(s) that I need to grab (instant client?  full?) in order to do the above?
